# Change html attribute when input value changes

Tags: javascript

**What I have:**

- a form in my `index.html`(see the html below)
- three additional html pages (`page1.html`, `page2.html`, `page3.html`)

**My goal is to:**

- change the `action` attribute if `<input>` 
  has a text-value that matches `"bubble"`.

  - for example:

    - **if** `<input>` value contains/matches string=`"bubble"` **then** `action="page1.html"`
    - **if** `<input>` value contains/matches string=`"wall"` **then** `action="page2.html"`
    - **if** `<input>` value contains/matches string=`"perfume"` **then** `action="page3.html"`

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="text" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button> 
</form>
```

**Question:**

What type of JavaScript eventlistener should I use to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here is a possible soluton:

Added the class `form1` to your form.

```
<form class="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="text" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button> 
</form>
```

In the JavaScript-code below I have used the `"keyup"` event in order to detect if the user input contains the word `"bubble"`.

```
const form1= document.querySelector(".form1"); //fetching your form-element
const myInput = document.querySelector("#myInput"); //fetching your input-element

myInput.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => { //This function will run whenever the user presses a keyboard-button
    const userInput = event.target.value;
    if(containsBubble(userInput)){
        updateAction(form1, "/page1.html");
    }else{
        updateAction(form1, "");
    }
});

const updateAction = (element, str) => {
        element.removeAttribute("action"); // remove the old action
        element.setAttribute("action", str); // add a new action
}

const containsBubble = (str) => { // This function returns true if str contains "bubble" (Otherwise, it returns false).
    const regex = "[Bb][Uu][Bb][Bb][Ll][Ee]"; //here is a regex for "bubble" (capital letters are included)
    const found = str.match(regex);
    if(found){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code before editing worked, when exact text is entered into input field. This one is not working for some reason. 

I forgot to add button in form below input field
    <button type="submit">submit</button>

Comment: @Djmiticbtc do you mean the one that use ```addEventListener("change", (event) => ....``` ??

Comment: yes, that one addEventListener("change", (event) => .... worked great, but I think your edited version is the one that I need, but I can't find where is the problem.

Comment: @Djmiticbtc give me a minute, I will try and fix it

Comment: @Djmiticbtc it should work now!

Comment: @Djmiticbtc I noticed that the ```keyup``` event is the best one!

Comment: works great! thank you very much!

Comment: @Djmiticbtc no problem! You can remove the ```event.preventDefault();``` if you want.

Comment: @Djmiticbtc I changed it again, I  think it is perfect now

Answer (score 0):

Use the includes method on the text value of your input box:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

You could watch for the submit of the form. Something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="text" />
</form>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('onsubmit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const inputValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

    if (/wall/.test(value)) {
      post('/page1.html', {text: value})
    }
  })

  function post(path, params, method='post') {

  // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
  // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  form.method = method;
  form.action = path;

  for (const key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
      hiddenField.name = key;
      hiddenField.value = params[key];

      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
  }
}
</script>
```

The code is untested and may have syntax errors so be ready to debug it.

Also, I'm assuming that you are trying to do a POST request instead of a GET request